# MFMailComposeViewController loads a blank white screen

Tags: iphone, email, ipod-touch

I'm testing on an iPod Touch running OS 3.1.3

Trying to allow users to send an email from within the app - but when the following code is executed, the entire screen just turns completely blank / white.

Any ideas on why this is happening?
I've got the MessageUI framework in the project.
I'm importing and delegating in the header file:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

And here's the code, pretty standard:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"App Feedback"];
    [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xyz@gmail.com"]];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
    }
```

And then I have the didFinishWithResult function that would dismiss the ModalViewController when the email has been sent.

But again, all I get is a blank white screen on my iPod Touch.   =/

Thanks!

Comment: Why have you used the name `picker` for the Mail controller?

Comment: You can use whatever name you want - you're creating a new MFMailComposeViewController and naming it *picker or *picklesAndCheese or whatever you want

Comment: Wow this question is more than three years old. I have no issues with composing email anymore but I'm also not doing anything with iOS 3.1.3 anymore...  =)

Comment: @RansLearns Sure, but it's good practice to name objects something that relates to the class to which they belong.  For example, `mailComposeController` or something like that.  All Apple's sample code does this with objects descended from `UIViewController`.  That was my point, clearly you can name it what you like!

Comment: Gotcha. Honestly I believe I got it from stackoverflow when I was first learning to email from within an app and never had to change it in all the years since. Seems common on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706673/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-not-dismissing?rq=1 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934470/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-not-dismissing-from-view

Answer (score 0):

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        MFMailComposeViewController *mail=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate=self;
        [mail setSubject:@"App Feedback"];          
        [mail setMessageBody:@"*your message  content*" isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
        [mail release];         
    }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at sample code from apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Listings/Classes_MessageComposerViewController_m.html

-(IBAction)showMailPicker:(id)sender {

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));

if (mailClass != nil) {
        [self displayMailComposerSheet];

    if ([mailClass canSendMail]) {
        [self displayMailComposerSheet];
    }
    else {
        feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send mail.";
    }
}
else    {
    feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
    feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send mail.";
}
```

}

-(void)displayMailComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

```
[picker setSubject:@"Hello from California!"];



NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];


NSString *emailBody = @"It is raining in sunny California!";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
        didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

```
feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
// Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending canceled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail saved";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending failed";
        break;
    default:
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail not sent";
        break;
}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}