# MFMailComposeViewController not dismissing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have the following code that gets called in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  The issue is, when I click the cancel button, it prompts for save draft or discard.  But when I click either, the view does not dismiss.  I've used the same code in a pre iOS 5 app and it dismissed fine.  Any ideas?  I have the MFMailComposeViewController delegate protocol in the interface.

```
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {

            MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            [picker setSubject:@"Support"];

            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"contact@app.com"]; 

            [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            NSString *emailBody = text;
            [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Use:**

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

**DEPRECATED FROM IOS 6.0:**

Add this method to your class:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Have fun

Comment: This method is deprecated now, Hope this may work instead of above dismissing code...[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 7):

There could be several problems:

1. Not adding protocol implemantation in the .h

   ```
   @interface yourClass : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
   ```
2. Not adding the relevant function in .m:

   ```
   -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:    (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```
3. My error was not setting the correct delegate, but I fixed it :) and now it works for me:

   ```
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

"dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:"is deprecated in **iOS 6.0**

**iOS 7 use:**

"dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:"

Answer (score 0):

I've described the problem and the way **it can be solved** more detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576408/691660

*I am not sure if Luda caught the core of the problem. No difference whether you specify the delegate or not, that does not work in case of modal+modal MFMailComposeViewController instance.*

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** Implementation:

Make sure your `MFMailComposeViewController` protocol and delegate is being called every time its function being executed.

This solves the issue of `MFMailComposeViewController` not being dismissed.

```
     let subj = "Test"
     let messageBody = "Test"
     let toRecipents = ["example@xyz.com"]
     let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
     mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
     mc.setSubject(subj)
     mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: true)
     mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
     self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```