# MFMailComposeViewController refuse to dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

This is driving me nuts. This snippet of code lets the user send an email with an image which is created within the app. Everything works perfectly except the `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` - the `MFMailComposeViewController` won't dismiss.

I used these three possibly problems https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217443/5274566 as my start to solve the problem, but it still won't work. The controller stays despite the fact than an mail has been sent or `cancel` has been tapped.

The protocol implementation `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` is added.

```
func mailOpen(alertAction: UIAlertAction) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mailcontroller = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailcontroller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        mailcontroller.setSubject("Subject")
        let completeImage = newImage! as UIImage
        mailcontroller.addAttachmentData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(completeImage, CGFloat(1.0))!, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "Image")
        mailcontroller.setMessageBody("<html><body><p>Message</p></body></html>", isHTML: true)

        self.present(mailcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send the e-mail. Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Got it!")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}//end of mail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is you have written the `didFinishWithResult:` delegate method inside the `mailOpen` function, so it will never be called and the dismissing code won't be executed ever.

```
func mailOpen(alertAction: UIAlertAction)
{
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
    {
        let mailcontroller = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailcontroller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        mailcontroller.setSubject("Subject")
        let completeImage = newImage! as UIImage
        mailcontroller.addAttachmentData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(completeImage, CGFloat(1.0))!, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "Image")
        mailcontroller.setMessageBody("<html><body><p>Message</p></body></html>", isHTML: true)

        self.present(mailcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {

        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send the e-mail. Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Got it!")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }
}//end of mail

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?)
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Opening brace should not be wrapped (see https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#spacing).

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ There's no reason to edit someone's answer just to change the placement of curly braces. Different people prefer different styles.

Comment: @deville: There is no official document saying that which style should be followed. I prefer this style as it is very easier to me for matching opening and closing brace.

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake

Answer (score -3):

here:

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

you're dismissing your own ViewController, rather than the `MFMailComposeViewController`

It should be:

```
controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```